# Recursive directive and infinite loop

Tags: angularjs

Looks like I somehow made an infinite loop in AngularJS directive compilation.
Please help me find out how to fix that.

Plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/2mvvCGYYYahOcEnWON9k

Don't press "Run" before reading the code - your browser can stop respond.

Code of directive:

```
    directive(
  'mlgPermissionCard', function() {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'mlgPermissionCard.html',
      restrict:    'AE',
      scope:       {
        branch: '=mlgPermissionCard'
      }
    };
  })
```

Template:

```
<div>
    <div class="pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></div>
    <div>{{ branch.name }}</div>
    <div class="list-group">
        <div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="child in branch.children">-->
            <div mlg-permission-card="child"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**
Working code of nested directives, maybe will be useful for somebody:
https://github.com/MLG/angular-mlg-permission-card

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're running into some Angular compile/link issues because you're using the directive recursively inside of itself.

If, instead, you manually assemble the template in the post link function it will work.

Here's a working fork of your Plunker.
http://plnkr.co/edit/E5fycjLYzKw1KxRqv9uj

Comment: Your answer and this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/T0BgQR?p=preview were helpful to solve issue. Thanks.